# Apache Tika hangs forever while detecting MIME type from URL

Tags: java, mime-types, apache-tika

I'm trying to detect MIME type for the resource located at: `https://www.futureelectronics.com/fr/search/?text=something`.

But when running this Java code based on Apache Tika `detect` method it never returns something:

```java
package mypacakge;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.tika.Tika;

public class ExampleApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        URL url = new URL("https://www.futureelectronics.com/fr/search/?text=something");
        Tika tika = new Tika();
        String mimeType = tika.detect(url);
        System.out.println(mimeType);
    }
    
}
```

By investigating the implementation of the `detect` method I saw that it relies on the `java.net.URLConnection` `getContentType` method. And this is the one that is blocking.

So here I have two questions:

- Do you have any idea why this specific URL is causing Tika `detect` to hang?
- `java.net.URLConnection` can have a read timeout configured. But from the Tika library level how can I control this read timeout configuration?

My Tika version:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
        <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```